# I find New declaration called "reportWebVitals();" in index.js in create react app

Tags: javascript

I am new in react and trying to begin a new project instance, so I have used some internet courses for that but when I downloaded create-react-app project(from the link https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app ), I found new Syntax in the "Index.js file" not the same as in my course as following:

**The index.js syntax in the  new downloaded create-react-app project (I prefer to get rid of it because I am not familiar with it):**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
reportWebVitals();
```

**The syntax the I actually familiar with (which i found it in the course)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

My question is: can I use the "old" syntax in the course (2015 update) with the new downloaded create-react-app project(from the link https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app )

Many thanks if someone tell me if I have choice; preferable or mandatory to use the new syntax and if that affects my project.